# Objective C Which Alert did the button press come from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uialertview

another probably simple iPhone obj-c question for you...

I have a couple of alerts which have buttons in them that are presented to the user in certain circumstances, both are part of one view. Now I know how to tell which button was pressed, but how do I know which alert the button pressed is related to?

Any ideas would be really handy! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a tag to each of the alerts, and compare the tag of the alert caught at the delegate method didDismissWithButtonIndex.

Set tag as, `alert.tag = 10;`
and check in delegate as
if `(alertView.tag == 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a simple delgate for your alert views.

For exemple using : alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:

you will be able to know which alert view the button pressed is related to.

Answer (score 0):

You can call UIAlertView's Delegate method explained below...and check for title or alert message like this.. here i had given you the example of title...

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{   
    if (buttonIndex == 0 && [alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Invalid"]) 
    {
              //Your Stuff goes here
    }
}
```